# Usage of "cerr" versus "wcerr" and available defining Macro

Tags: c++, windows, character-encoding

**1.** When would one use `cerr` as opposed to `wcerr`?

Despite `cerr` and `wcerr` being [specified](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/cerr) as for character streams and wide-character streams (respectively), all of the below statements appear to compile with no issues (and in the same environment):

```
std::cerr << "some text" << std::endl;
std::wcerr << "some text" << std::endl;
std::cerr << TEXT("some text") << std::endl;
std::wcerr << TEXT("some text") << std::endl;
```

This implies that `cerr` and `wcerr` are interchangeable (at least in the above contexts). To put this in context of other character and wide-character based objects, only 2 of the below declarations compile without error (on the same system as that above):

```
std::string s1("some text"); 
std::wstring s2("some text"); // Error
std::string s3(TEXT("some text")); // Error
std::wstring s4(TEXT("some text"));
```

**2.** Is there an available Windows Macro that appropriately defines an identifier as either `cerr` or `wcerr` based on the programming environment?

(i.e. a macro that is to `cerr` and `wcerr` as `TCHAR` is to `char` and `wchar_t`)

Thanks.

Comment: All output streams define [overloads of `operator<<`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt2) for `char`. So the `wchar_t` based streams will also accept `char` characters and strings. That `std::cerr` also accepts `wchar_t` based strings and characters could be a compiler-specific extension?  [The `std::basic_string` template](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) have no specified overloads to accept strings of the other type (so `std::wstring` is *only* for `std::wchar_t`, and `std::string` is *only* for `char`).

Comment: `std::cerr << L"こんにちは世界" << std::endl;` doesn't compile for me in visual studio, I'm guessing you're compiling with unicode disabled. The general recommendation in modern code is to not use Window's unicode macros and `TCHAR` and choose to work with either wide or narrow chars

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude "That std::cerr also accepts wchar_t based strings and characters could be a compiler-specific extension?" I couldn't say. Although, the Visual Studio extensions that are currently installed appear to be unrelated (e.g. Visual Studio IntelliCode or Dotnet Extensions for Test Explorer...).

Comment: @AlanBirtles "I'm guessing you're compiling with unicode disabled". When I enter your line of code and attempt to save, Visual Studio offers me to re-save the file as Unicode in order to "maintain [my] data". However, as apparent from the code in my post (OP) above, the output of the Macro: TEXT("s..."), is a wide-character string.

Comment: A "compiler extension" is not like something you install or add to Visual Studio, it's built into the compiler itself (or in the standard library) and means that it could add extra features not part of the standard language. Most compilers have such "extensions", they are generally not portable (i.e. an extension in one compiler doesn't exist in any other compiler) and should be avoided.

Comment: There are typically flags that could be added when building to disable compiler extensions. For  the MSVC compiler use [`/permissive-`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/permissive-standards-conformance?view=msvc-160)